# How do I rid my new plastic appliance of its plastic smell?

Tags: equipment, coffee

I've just purchased a new coffee maker, and it has a terrible plastic smell to it. It smells like something between new car and hot glue gun.

I've run two or three pots of water through it, but the smell lingers.

How do I get rid of this smell?

Comment: I would expect the stuff that makes plastics smell to be more on the oil/alcohol soluble side then water soluble...

Answer (score 5):

You could also try running white vinegar through the coffeemaker. It's a technique used to [clean the coffeemaker](http://www.howtocleanthings.com/how-to-clean-coffee-maker.htm). Vinegar in general is good for [getting rid of smells](http://organicclothing.blogs.com/my_weblog/2007/02/removing_odors_.html), so I'm thinking it will be useful here.

Comment: Vinegar isn't good at getting rid of smells at all. It has some limited use in smelly cases: 1. If a smell is caused by a bacteria colony and the bacteria are still alive, it will probably kill them. 2. It can dissolve some grime water can't. 3. It can mask a bad smell with its own stink. So it can work for your dirty laundry, but there is no point to use it on clean plastic.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a few runs with coffee to overcome the smell and taste. Since these runs are not for drinking you can use a cheap kind of coffee.

Comment: Just my thought.

Comment: I tried this, but I'm not convinced that it's having any more effect than water alone -- the smell seems to be coming from the water chamber, which never touches the coffee.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider running a solution of PLAIN Oxilean through it a couple of times, and then multiple clean water rinses.  On the off chance you're a home brewer, I'd suggest PBW instead, but PLAIN oxiclean should do the trick.  Stay away from any scented versions.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a Keurig, fill the entire water container with straight vinegar.  Run though one or two cycles to fill the heat chamber with the vinegar. Leave the unit on with the vinegar for at least four hours.  After that, run remaining vinegar and clean water through as many cycles as necessary until the vinegar taste is gone.  Plastic taste will be gone from coffee.  It will take awhile for the plastic smell to wear off the outside of the unit.